# Do I need to make a third accumulator for saving the item types in this while-loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

all
First off, hope everyone had a great thanksgiving.
Second, I cannot figure out how to do this. I  need to write a program for a wedding planner. They wish to create a gift registry for each couple. They want the gifts broken down by the whether the gift giver is on the bride side or groom side. They also know that specific gifts (toasters, silverware, and stemware) tend to be repeated so they want those gifts listed and have the name of the gift giver under them. The repeating gifts are only the ones that have been told you by the client (toasters, silverware, and stemware) they do not want you to determine which gifts repeat, they are just looking for those specific three.

So my output should be appearing as:
Groom side: 
1. Tom: toaster
2. Bill: silverware
3. Bob: stemware
4. Steve: Lexus

Bride side: 
1. Jill: toaster
2. Suzy: silverware
3. Pat: stemware
4. Karen: horse

Multiple toasters by: 
Tom
Jill

But, it is not agreeing with what i've coded and am in a stump. I also cant figure out how to make the third accumulator (which im assuming I would have to make to store the different types of gifts ?) any input in which direction i should go would be great.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//Assumptions
var brideCounter = 0;
var groomCounter = 0;
var gift, sideOfFamily, groomAccum, brideAccum;
var giftBride, giftGroom,multipleItems;

//initializing loop
var registry = "yes";

//Start Looping
while (registry == "yes")
{
 name = prompt("What is your name?","");
 sideOfFamily = prompt("Which side of the family are you on? bride or groom","");
            if (sideOfFamily == "groom")
            {
            giftGroom = prompt("What type of gift do you have?","");
            groomCounter= groomCounter + 1;
                    if (groomCounter = 1)
                    {
                    groomAccum = "Groom Side:<br>" + groomCounter + ". " + name+ ": " + giftGroom;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    groomAccum = groomAccum + ", " + groomCounter + ". " + name + ": " + giftGroom;
                    }
                alert(groomAccum);
            }
            else
            {
            giftBride = prompt("What type of gift do you have?","");
            brideCounter = brideCounter + 1;
                    if (brideCounter = 1)
                    {
                    brideAccum =    "Bride Side: " + brideCounter + ". " + name + ": " + giftBride;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    brideAccum = brideAccum + ", " + brideCounter + ". " + name  + ": " + giftBride;
                    }
                alert(brideAccum);
                }
                registry = prompt("Are you registering for the wedding gifts?","");
}

//Output
document.write(groomAccum + brideAccum);
document.write(multipleItems);



// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Off-topic: [never use `document.write`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the assign operator (`=`) instead of a comparison one (`===` or `==`).

Better use `===`, which is faster than `==`, and if you forgot one the code will also work.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators for full information about comparison operators.

I have also cleaned your code.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fxz6/)

```
//Assumptions
var keys = ['groom','bride'],
    counter = {bride: 0, groom: 0},
    gift = {},
    accum = {bride: '', groom: ''},
    sideOfFamily;

//initializing loop
var registry = true;

//Start Looping
while (registry)
{
    name = prompt("What is your name?","");

    do {
        sideOfFamily = (prompt("Which side of the family are you on? bride or groom", keys[Math.random()*2 | 0]) || '').toLowerCase();
    } while (keys.indexOf(sideOfFamily) === -1);

    gift[sideOfFamily] = prompt("What type of gift do you have?","");
    if(++counter[sideOfFamily] === 1) {
        accum[sideOfFamily] = sideOfFamily[0].toUpperCase() + sideOfFamily.substring(1) + " Side:\n";
    } else {
        accum[sideOfFamily] += ", ";
    }
    accum[sideOfFamily] += counter[sideOfFamily] + ". " + name + ": " + gift[sideOfFamily];
    alert(accum[sideOfFamily]);
    registry = confirm("Are you registering for the wedding gifts?");
}

//Output
output.innerHTML = '';
output.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(accum.groom + '\n\n' + accum.bride)
);
```

If you want to support old browsers which don't support `indexOf`, use the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility

Comment: `===` faster than `==`? I find that hard to believe. Where did you get that? I get the logic, but I think JS is smarter than that.

Comment: I appreciate you cleaning up my code, but now I dont know what its doing. Im in a beginning class and just starting to code. That is a total foreign language to me. Ive been told that how I code is awkward as well, but it is how the teacher does it. Sometimes it makes things easier...I also just ran it and its giving me an error that I have no idea how to fix :/

Comment: Says that "object doesn't support property or method 'index.Of' line 24 char 18. Course that will be different on your screen

Comment: @Rudie I have seen that everywhere... e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1529630. But I guess if the type is the same (like here) the difference can be negligible.

Comment: @jim Maybe the error is that old versions of IE don't support `indexOf`... But it's weird that the error says `index.Of` and not `indexOf`, crazy IE. Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility can fix that.